# Center of group ring is generated by characters

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}[G]$ be the group ring of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$.
Show that
$$B =\left\{\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{\pi}(g)g : \pi:G\to GL(V)\text{ a representation}\right\}$$
(where $\chi_\pi$ is the character of $\pi$) is a linear basis for $Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$.

If $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ is a class function, then it is constant on conjugacy classes and so for all $h\in G$ we have
$$h\sum_{g\in G} f(g)g=\sum_{g\in G}f(g)hg=\sum_{g\in G} f(h^{-1}gh)h(h^{-1}gh)=\sum_{g\in G} f(g)gh=\left(\sum_{g\in G} f(g)g\right)h$$
so in particular $B\subseteq Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$. However, I am not sure how to show that it forms a basis. I tried to write an element $v\in Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$ as a linear combination of elements in $B$ but I couldn't make it work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you know about characters and class functions? If you know that characters are orthogonal for the appropriate hermitian structure, and if you know the dimensions involved, it should not be too hard.

Comment: What are the $\chi_{\pi}$? Irreducible characters or class functions in general? You should know that $Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$ is spanned by the different conjugacy class sums $\sum_{x \in Cl(g)}x$. If the $\chi_{\pi}$ are class functions than take one that is $1$ on a particular conjugacy class and $0$ elsewhere. Do this for each conjugacy class and you are done.

Comment: @CaptainLama I know that the characters are orthogonal, but I haven't learnt about hermitian structures yet!

Comment: @NickyHekster the $\chi_\pi$ are characters. I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: But then, what does it mean for you that they are orthogonal? You can only be orthogonal with respect to a certain euclidean/hermitian (or similar) structure. In any case, if they are orthogonal they are linearly independent. Then you just have to check that there is the correct number of irreducible characters.

Comment: @CaptainLama We proved that charcaters are orthogonal in the inner product space $L(G)=\{f\mid f:G\to\mathbb{C}\}$ with respect to the inner product $\langle a,b\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}a(g)\overline{b(g)}$. I know we can identify $L(G)$ with $C[G]$ by sending $f$ to $\sum_{g\in G}f(g)g$, but I am not sure how to send the product in $L(G)$ (given by $a*b(x)=\sum_{g\in G}a(xg^{-1})b(g)$) to the product in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ (given by $\sum_g\lambda_g g\sum_h\mu_h h=\sum_{g,h}\lambda_g\mu_h gh$).